# Capturing latitude and longitude on marker drag in MapQuest

Tags: javascript, mapquest

I can't seem to find a way to get the latitude and longitude from existing markers in MapQuest.

I currently set my directions map using:

```
var map = L.mapquest.map('map', {
    center: [selfLatitude, selfLongitude],
    layers: L.mapquest.tileLayer('map'),
    zoom: 13
});

L.mapquest.directions().route({
    start: [selfLatitude, selfLongitude],
    end: [otherLatitude, otherLongitude]
});
```

This produces a Map with the two points and the direction between them.

I am able to move the `end` point on the map but want to capture the **modified** `latitude` and `longitude`.

What is the proper way to target and get the coordinates from individual markers in a MapQuest Map using the mapquest.js javascript library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this would be an easy solution, but I could not find anything easily in their documentation. I tried picking apart their examples and looking everywhere for bit of information. After assuming this would work, but didn't because `getLatLng()` is not a function:

```
  popup.on('dragend', function(event) {
    var marker = event.target;
    var position = marker.getLatLng().wrap();
    showLL(position, 'USER_DEFINED');
  });
```

At some point I decided to stop looking at the doc's they provided and tried to look at their [Lat/Long finder example](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/tools/latitude-longitude-finder/) and look further into the `event.target` object that was returned and tried to find anything related to the lat and long.

I know you asked for a "proper" way, but I honestly couldn't find one and thought I should share anyways.

The below is def not an official way to do this, but I believe it works. For some reason the `moveend` event is fired whether the start or end is moved, but I only log the end lat/long anyways.

I noticed that `marker._layers[prop].locationIndex` was mixed in the layers obj and 0 seems to correlate to the start marker and 1 seemed to point to the end marker.

Here's what I came up with:

```
let latLng1 = new L.LatLng(35.6009, -82.554);
let latLng2 = new L.LatLng(35.7796, -78.6382);

let map = L.mapquest.map('map', {
  center: latLng1,
  layers: L.mapquest.tileLayer('map'),
  zoom: 13
});

let directions = L.mapquest.directions();

directions.route({
  start: latLng1,
  end: latLng2
});

map.on('moveend', function(event) {
  let marker = event.target;
  for (let prop in marker._layers) {
    if (!marker._layers.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

    // locationIndex- I am assuming 0 for start marker and 1 for end marker.
    if (marker._layers[prop].locationIndex === 1) {
      let latLong = marker._layers[prop]._latlng;
      console.log(latLong)
    }
  }
});
}
```

Comment: This does indeed work. I will wait for a couple of days to see if a more streamlined method pops up and if not, I will mark yours as the accepted answer.

Comment: Did you find any solutions ?